# best way to handle a timed

Tags: laravel, dynamic

I want to have a dynamic slider with a time of show for every image.
I know I can to do this with `Carbon:now()` and simple comparison with `experation_date`.

But is there a better way to handle such kind of thing in back-end, because with this way every time  that someone reloads the page this query should be run and it has pressure on the system.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to point out this resource: 
https://reinink.ca/articles/dynamic-relationships-in-laravel-using-subqueries